# How to use :empty pseudo-class and content property together?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I **wanted** to use CSS3's `:empty` psedo-class and CSS3's `content` property together to add some text to empty lists as demonstrated in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZesAC/2/

I **learned** that CSS only allows `content` in `:after` or `:before` pseudo-elements. Is there a solution that allows styling of empty lists?

---

As I learned in the comments, turns out you *can* use `content` anywhere in CSS3 (to no effect in the majority of browsers [as of 12/31/2012]) and only in `:after` and `:before` blocks in CSS2. (Thanks [@BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock))

If you don't mind being Firefox-specific, you can use the `-moz-only-whitespace` selector to make it behave a little more logically. (Thanks [@robertc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8655/robertc))

Comment: CSS3's `content` property is allowed anywhere but implementation is almost nonexistent. CSS2's `content` property is only allowed in `:after` and `:before`.

Comment: @BoltClock Ahh, I was mislead by what I read. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out I answered my own question in the asking:

http://jsfiddle.net/M6xZj/2/

You can use `:after` with the `:empty` element to add something after the UL.  It *is* empty, after all, so it's guaranteed to be located where the list was.

Comment: [Be careful with `:empty`](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/M6xZj/3/), see also [`:-moz-only-whitespace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:-moz-only-whitespace) (unfortunately not a standard).

Comment: Thanks @robertc. I know that :empty has some vaguely/very stupid behavior. Appreciate the warning though! Didn't now about `only-whitespace`! :) That's pretty cool.

Comment: Agreed. It's worth noting that `:empty` won't match things like `<div> </div>` (note the space, but will match `<div></div>` (without a space).

Answer (score 14):

`.some_class_name:empty::after{
    content: "-";
}`