# remove angular comments from html

Tags: css, angularjs

Is it possible to remove or disable the HTML comments angular produces?

```
<ol class="items">
    <!-- ngRepeat: item in list | orderBy:'time':true -->
</ol>
```

Its breaking CSS rules that use `:empty` pseudo class.

```
ol:empty {
    content: "No results";
}
```

In order for the rule to be applied, there needs to be no whitespace or comments:

```
<ol></ol>
```

Comment: As an alternative - you can use `ng-show` on `!list.length`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove helper HTML comments in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508412/remove-helper-html-comments-in-angular-js)

Comment: could use `ng-if` in markup instead of css to produce `No Results`

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs leaves comments in HTML is it possible to remove them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them)

Comment: I think it is dublicate.
I think answear is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them/41108749#41108749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding a class `.empty` with `ng-class="{ empty: !list.length }"` and applying the CSS rule that way without relying on the pseudoelement `:empty`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
```

But it can broke some plugins which have references on angular comments.

Answer (score 0):

The content property is used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements

[you can try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102362/css3-empty-selector-and-content-property)

Answer (score -1):

While not the most efficient or direct way to do it, you could use javascript to remove the contents of the elements. Something like this should work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('items').innerHTML = "";
```

I don't know what kind of structure you have, but I'm sure you could sneak this in before the CSS is loaded...

**Edit**

After reading the post linked by @zsong and this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165390/angularjs-leaves-comments-in-html-is-it-possible-to-remove-them), you might end up breaking Angular trying to do this. Only one way to find out I guess!